# Getting a value from the same row as the row the min() value comes from

Tags: mysql

Here's my query.

There's a complicated system, which requires this query. I'd like to know, how do I get the `currency` value from the same row the `min(j.price)` value comes from?

I know the query is a little messy but I'm essentially asking how to get a value from the same row that the value from a min() function comes from?

```
SELECT 
    count(p.name), p.name, p.image_url, p.type, p.number, p.productCode, p.productType, 
    p.material, p.blueprint, min(j.price) as price
FROM products AS p
left join (
    SELECT 
        p.token_id, p.name, p.image_url, p.type, p.number, p.productCode, 
        p.productType, p.material, p.blueprint, o2.order_id, o2.currency, 
        o2.eth_price, o2.price, o2.usd_price, o2.quantity, o2.isOurs, 
        o2.order_status, o2.updated_timestamp, ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (PARTITION BY order_status ORDER BY usd_price ASC) rn
    FROM products AS p
    left JOIN (
        SELECT token_id, MAX(updated_timestamp) AS Latest_order
        FROM orders
        GROUP BY token_id
    ) o1 ON p.token_id = o1.token_id
    left JOIN orders o2 ON o1.token_id = o2.token_id AND o1.Latest_order = o2.updated_timestamp
    where o2.order_status = 'active'
    ORDER BY name asc
) j on p.token_id = j.token_id
group by p.name, p.image_url, p.type, p.number, p.productCode, p.productType, p.material, p.blueprint
order by name
```

For @FanoFN
[image]

Comment: `where j.rn = 1`?

Comment: That just shows 1 row and doesn't add the currency.

Comment: It seems like the first few rows of the prices based on `ORDER BY j.price ASC` doesn't have corresponding `currency` value. Let's try this query `SELECT  price, currency  FROM orders WHERE price=0.000648;`. What result it returns?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` can help. So, instead of:

```
... , min(j.price) as price
```

How about something like this:

```
..., 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(j.price ORDER BY j.price ASC),',',1) AS price, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(j.currency ORDER BY j.price ASC),',',1) AS currency
```

It is quite long but it should work.

Refer this [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yqdT8Wev)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The prices remain correct but the currency is always NULL or an empty string. There should be plenty of NULLs but in the cases where there should be an ID, it's not showing.

Comment: What values does `GROUP_CONCAT(j.currency ORDER BY j.price ASC)` returns?

Comment: FYI, upon close inspection of your query, there's one part that is not functioning as how you intend it to be > the `left JOIN orders o2 .. ` part won't be a `LEFT JOIN` due to your `where o2.order_status = 'active'`.. this will become an `INNER JOIN` instead. Of you wish it to still perform as `LEFT JOIN` then you should change the `where o2.order_status = 'active'` to `AND o2.order_status = 'active'` as part of your `ON` condition.

Comment: Thanks - something that can be looked at once I figure out an answer :)

Comment: So, what is the output of `GROUP_CONCAT(j.currency ORDER BY j.price ASC)`?

Comment: Sorry - somehow completely missed that question. I've added an image to the post for you.